# Help with Complex Number (De Moivre's theorem)

Tags: complex-numbers

Please help with this question.

"Use De Moivre's theorem to solve $z^5 = -1$. By grouping the roots in complex conjugate pairs, show that: $z^5+1 = (z+1)(z^2 - 2z\cos(\pi/5) +1) = (z^2 - 2z\cos(3\pi/5) +1)$

I'd solved the roots as:
\begin{align}
cis(\pi/5)\\ 
cis(3\pi/5)\\ 
cis(\pi)\\
cis(-3\pi/5)\\
cis(-\pi/5)
\end{align} 
and I did notice that there are 2 conjugate pairs (3 technically if you consider pi and -pi). But where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think there is one $=$ too much in your factorisation. It should be
$$
z^5+1=(z+1)(z^2-2z\cos(\pi/5)+1)(z^2-2z\cos(3\pi/5)+1).
$$

Now to the solution:

If $\alpha$ is a zero of $p(z)$ then $(z-\alpha)$ is a factor of $p(z)$. With $p(z)=z^5+1$ you have found the zeros. Now pair the ones that are conjugate. So, you know that both $(z-\text{cis}(\pi/5))$ and $(z-\text{cis}(-\pi/5))$ factor $p(z)$, so $(z-\text{cis}(\pi/5))(z-\text{cis}(-\pi/5))$ is a factor of $p(z)$. Multiply them. Do the same with $\text{cis}(\pm 3\pi/5)$ and you will get your factorisation.

Comment: Thank you very much @mickep I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

**Applicable theory**:

(1) $cos(\alpha) + i sin(\alpha) = cos(\alpha \pm   2n\pi) + i sin(\alpha \pm   2n\pi)$ by the simple property that $sin$ and $cos$ have period $2\pi$.

(2) de Moivre's theorem says $(cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta))^n = cos(n\theta) + i sin(n\theta)$.

(3) The complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients ($z^5 + 1 = 0$ has real coefficients) occur in conjugate pairs

(4) $cos^2(\gamma) + sin^2(\gamma) = 1$

**Solution:**

Looking at $z^5 = -1$, clearly $|z| = 1$ and $z$ is then of the form $(cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta))$, so that  $(cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta))^5 = cos(5\theta) + i sin(5\theta) = -1$.

To solve this, note that $-1 = cos(\pi) + i sin(\pi)$, so that $5\theta = \pi$ is an obvious solution. The other solutions come from noting that $-1 = cos([1+2n]\pi) + i sin(1+2n]\pi)$. This gives no new values for -1 itself, but when we divide by 5 we can obtain all 5 roots of -1 in the form

1. $\pi/5$ (n=0)
2. $3\pi/5$ (n=1)
3. $5\pi/5 = \pi$ (n=2)
4. $7\pi/5 = $(n=3)
5. $9\pi/5 = $(n=4)

Why do we stop ? because after that the values repeat: $cos(11\pi/5) = cos(\pi/5)$, etc.

Since $z^5 + 1 = 0$ has real coefficients its complex roots occur in conjugate pairs, so that we should look to restate the 5 roots in a way that this is obvious, i.e. $\pi/5$; $3\pi/5$; $\pi$; $-3\pi/5$ (by subtracting $2\pi$ from $7\pi/5$); $-\pi/5$ (by subtracting $2\pi$ from $9\pi/5$).

Now we can factorize $z^5+1 = [z - cos(\pi) - i sin(\pi)].[z - cos(\pi/5) - i sin(\pi/5)].[z - cos(-\pi/5) - i sin(-\pi/5)].[z - cos(3\pi/5) - i sin(3\pi/5)].[z - cos(-3\pi/5) - i sin(-3\pi/5)]$ and simplify this noting that $cos(\pi) = -1$, $sin(\pi) = 0$, $cos(-\beta) = cos(\beta) $, $sin(-\beta) = -sin(\beta)$.

$z^5+1 = [z - (-1)].[z - cos(\pi/5) - i sin(\pi/5)].[z - cos(\pi/5) + i sin(\pi/5)].[z - cos(3\pi/5) - i sin(3\pi/5)].[z - cos(3\pi/5) + i sin(-3\pi/5)]$

$z^5+1 = [z +1].[z^2 - 2z cos(\pi/5) + cos^2 (\pi/5) + sin^2 (\pi/5)].[z^2 - 2z cos(3\pi/5) + cos^2 (3\pi/5) + sin^2 (3\pi/5)]$ and using $cos^2(\gamma) + sin^2(\gamma) = 1$ get the final result:

$z^5+1 = [z +1].[z^2 - 2z cos(\pi/5) + 1].[z^2 - 2z cos(3\pi/5) + 1]$

**P.S.**

The manipulation is a whole lot easier is you use Euler's formula instead, i.e. $z = r e ^{i\theta}$, where in this case $r = |z| = 1$. It follows that $z^5 = r^5 (e^{i\theta})^5 =  r^5 (e^{5i\theta})$

Comment: Thanks I had already solved it from an previous answer, but thanks for the effort, it's very thoughtful. I will look into the Euler's formula method.